# function lm displaying wrong values

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Here's my code:

```
#Dados parte I gráfico 1
g <- c(9.80)
t <- c(26.87,24.81,22.75,17.59,11.47)
t.1oscilação <- c(t/10)
l <- c(180,156,131,75.5,32.9)
l.cm <- c(l/100)
l.cm
t.1oscilação
ajuste=lm(t.1oscilação~l)
ajuste
#Ajuste da escla para o papel milimetrado(feito por regra de 3)
l2 <- c(l.cm/0.011)
t2 <- c(t.1oscilação/0.011)
l2
t2
ajuste2=lm(t2~l2)
ajuste2
#mudança de variável para linearizar a equação
a.1<- c(2*pi)
a.2 <- c(sqrt(9.8))
a <- c(a.1/a.2)
x <- c(sqrt(l.cm))
a
x
y <- c(x*a)
y
ajuste3=lm(y~x)
ajuste3
#Ajuste da equação linearizada para dimensões do papel milimetrado
x2 <- c(x/0.0083)
y2 <- c(y/0.01)
x2
y2
ajuste4=lm(y2~x2)
ajuste4
```

so, when i call ajuste3 and ajuste4, i got this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRHrT.png

and, if i run another script only with values for ajuste3(now called ajuste) and ajuste4(now called ajuste4), like the code below, it shows:

```
x <- c(1.341,1.248,1.144,0.868,0.573)
y <- c (2.692,2.506,2.297,1.743,1.151)  
ajuste=lm(y~x)
ajuste
x2 <- c(161.56627, 150.36145, 137.83133 ,104.57831,69.03614)
y2 <- c(269.2,250.6,229.7,174.3,115.1)
ajuste2=lm(y2~x2)
ajuste2
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5OaG.png
so, i belive the 2nd code is the right value for ajuste3 and ajuste4. But why i have this stranger value for ajuste3 and ajuste4 in the 1st code?

Comment: I'm not understanding what is strange about this. Can you elaborate? All I see is that you changed the x/x2 and y/y2 values and got different outputs.